Bad alloc from variable shadowing?
The executable from the following code
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(void) {    
  std::string filename = "/home/amat/test.txt";
  if (true) {
    std::filesystem::path filename = std::filesystem::path(filename);
    std::cout << "Filename (path): " << filename.string() << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Filename (string): " << filename << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

terminates with
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted

Why does this exactly happen? Not that one should seriously write code like this, but still, shouldn't variable shadowing work here?
The std::filesystem::path constructor accepts a reference, yes, but why does it break?

warning: variable 'filename' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization

std::filesystem::path filename = std::filesystem::path(filename); is using the same filename that is just being declared to initialize itself (not the one declared before the if).

equivalent to: int x = ++x;

See dupes: Calling function with variable that is being initialized and What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?.

Turning on your compiler warnings is vital!  Always do it.

Also always enable all warnings.

And to be clear, your issue has nothing to do with variable shadowing.  Your entire main could be the single line std::filesystem::path filename = std::filesystem::path(filename);.  You would see the same issue.

I don't think the dupes are relevant here. It is clear from the title that the question is about using the shadowed filename from before the if. This is not what actually happened here as I explained in my answer. Therefore I reopened.

@user12002570 Yes I know, but this is what the question is about and it's exactly what I gave as an answer. But the dupes do not explain it.

@user12002570 you keep deciding what the question is, ignoring the fact that the OP is the one asking it. And they asked about the shadowed variable.

@DrewDormann yeah, but it's not an argument that shorter code suffers from this, too. The question is why this still happens here when using the shadowed filename.

@wohlstad And for that shadowed case there is already another dupe: Enum in c++ not working as expected, instead is initalized with first value. So instead of reopening that could've been added to the dupe list. No need to repeat the same thing again and again. There is a reason why we can add 5 dupes in the dupe list.

@user12002570 I always do. And this code wasn't written by me. The question is more of a conceptual nature, because one would perhaps assume the shadowing prevents this.

Even better dupe that explains both of the cases: Enum in c++ not working as expected, instead is initalized with first value

@RichardCritten I really think this dumbs down the question so much, it's not the same question anymore.

@Amaterasu Why would you assume shadowing would help?  std::filesystem::path filename = std::filesystem::path(filename); introduces a new filename variable that shadows the one in main, meaning std::filesystem::path(filename) doesn't use the variable from main.

@NathanOliver Yes exactly this is explained in the other dupe:  Enum in c++ not working as expected, instead is initalized with first value. You should close it as dupe again.

@NathanOliver of course, it could be considered "strange" if C++ departs from the usual order with declaration always coming first, before assignment. But if there ever was a sensible exception to depart from the rule, it was here, because there is an older shadowed variable that could be used. Or perhaps I'm just too hesitant to discard code by senior devs with 25+ years experience as a brain fart.

C++ has enough rules with exceptions, IMHO we don't need more but less.  I am happy that as soon as a name is declared its is useable and that's it, no exceptions.  Do remember being a senior dev does not mean you are infallible.  We all still get brain farts from time to time.  To me this is really a naming issue.  std::filesystem::path filename should have been called pathname or something along those lines instead of reusing filename

"PS: There's no typo to be found here, it can be compiled."  The typos that compile successfully are the worst kind.  std::filesystem::path filename = std::filesystem::path(filename); is such a typo.  The compiler, at best, can warn you that this line of code is certainly not what you wanted to type.

@DrewDormann It's not a typo if one types this deliberately and thinks it could work. And compiling is done with -Wall -Werror and some other W-flags, but the code author turned that off. ‍♀️ Now, maybe one "cleverly" assumes there's a special rule so that shadowed variables remain accessible until the new variable has been defined, not just declared? Sounds sensible. Though I don't know such behavior from any language with block scope & shadowing. But C++ already has so many strange exceptions...

@Amaterasu I don't agree.  "Typo" is short for "Typographical error".  You can not fix a typo by thinking that it's correct.  You are welcome to disagree, however.  Multiple high-ranking users concluded that you typed something incorrectly.  It is the correct close reason for this particular site.

@DrewDormann nobody concluded that "I typed something incorrectly", just that I wrote something incorrect. So to conclude from that, that I made a typo, is pretty insane. According to this all factual errors or errors in thought are  typos.

@Amaterasu I'm sorry if this is feeling insane to you, but this really isn't the correct site to debate what "typo" means.  Many people considered your mistake a typo, and I can't change that.

a typographical error means the author intended to write something else than what they wrote. Thats not the case here. The question is about code that was written like it is and expecting it to work in a certain way. Explaining what they should have written instead is related, but not sufficient as answer.

In this line:
std::filesystem::path filename = std::filesystem::path(filename);

The filename used as an initializer is not the one you declared before the if, but rather the one that is just being declared in the current line.
But since its lifetime hasn't started yet you invoke undefined behavior.
Turning on all warnings would have helped.
E.g. clang is giving this proper warning about it:
warning: variable 'filename' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization

Live demo
Note that the filename you declared before the if is actually not relevant here.

I'd say its lifetime hasn't started yet. "Uninitialized" usually implies the lifetime has started.

@HolyBlackCat rephrased according to your suggestion.

Even better dupe that explains both of the cases: Enum in c++ not working as expected, instead is initalized with first value

@user12002570 I don't like that one because it doesn't mention lifetime.

@HolyBlackCat You can add an answer there. The question and problem is the same.

@user12002570 IMO it's your job if you want to close this question as a dupe of that one.

@HolyBlackCat I already have an answer there that explain the problem and it has more than enough info there for this one to be closed as a dupe of that. Also, the validity of an answer(in the target dupe) doesn't matter when closing a question as a dupe. All  that maters is whether the problem is same or not.

@user12002570 "the validity of an answer(in the target dupe) doesn't matter" It absolutely does matter. The system doesn't let you use dupe targets without upvoted or accepted answers, in an attempt to enforce that. Also the help center has this: "The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer ..." If you use dupe targets with bad answers (this one isn't necessarily that bad, I mean in general) you're neither helping OP nor helping to build the repository of knowledge that SO is supposed to be

perhaps worth mentioning that passing a reference to something to its own constructor by itself is ok. Its the fact that the constructor reads from the reference that causes the issue.
